# Unable to locate the elements by selenium webdriver in python after moving from one page to another

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

[Each bar a has a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1ie6.png)Am trying to automate a web page

an another page has to displayed from a menu of buttons , here am facing a problem where the elements in the next page are not located by saying no element found.

is there any way to link both of them??

someone could please help me?????

Comment: next page opens in a tab or in a new Windows ?

Comment: it does pops out from a list of menu

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML. You can check my answer below , it might solve your issue.

Comment: Once you click on Home, wireless , internet , it redirects to new page right ?

Comment: No its going to another frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on what cruisepandey said in python it's:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

`-1` means the newly created page.

you may also have to do something like:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('foobar')
```

if the website is divided in frames.

Comment: Yes you are correct for iframe scenario. But this question is regarding moving between pages/tabs/windows.

Answer (score 0):

This code is in **Java**, Similarly you can convert it to **Python**.

If after clicking on next button, Page opens in a new tab then you have to switch the focus of WebDriver to that window.

For that you have to use :

```
driver.switchTo.window(String args0);
```

You can use this code for full implementation :

```
public static void main(String args0){

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

  //Some operations on Page 1  (Page 1 is cuurent Page that you are working).
 //Click on next button on Page 1.

  ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

  // performs some operations on Page 2

   driver.close();
   driver.switchTo.windows(tabs.get(0));
}
```

That's it !

**Note :** This code would work for new tabs that opens after clicking on next button and for new Windows also.

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: Thanks for ua answer but the page pops out from a list of menu.. how could i solve this.